# Loop through all elements in SoapMessage body and return the node that I want

Tags: java, soap, recursion

I am looping thru this soap fault XML response from SoapMessage. I'm able to parse thru the nodes and find the Node that I want, but how can I return the Node value back to the calling method. As I'm calling the same method again to get to the value. Here is my code.

```
   Response XML:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
        <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
        </soapenv:Code>
        <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">Failed</soapenv:Text>
        </soapenv:Reason>
        <Detail xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <axis2:documentFault xmlns:axis2="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" xmlns:ns2="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xsd">
                <axis2:SystemInfo>
                    <axis2:ServiceContext>
                         <axis2:consumerPartnerId>XXX</axis2:consumerPartnerId>
                    </axis2:ServiceContext>
                    <axis2:ReturnInfo>
                        <axis2:returnSeverity>Error</axis2:returnSeverity>
                        <axis2:commonReturnMessage>Exception</axis2:commonReturnMessage>
                        <axis2:ReturnInfo>
                            <axis2:ReturnCode>008</axis2:ReturnCode>
                            <axis2:ReturnMessage>This is the response error description</axis2:ReturnMessage>
                        </axis2:ReturnInfo>
                    </axis2:ReturnInfo>
                </axis2:SystemInfo>
            </axis2:documentFault>
         </Detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>

    Element dom = responseBody;
        // Calling method
        String soapResult = getChildren(dom);
        // rest of the code


    private String getChildren(Node n){
    NodeList innerResultList = n.getChildNodes();
    String value="";
    for (int l = 0; l < innerResultList.getLength(); l++) {
        Node currentNode = innerResultList.item(l);
        System.out.println(currentNode.getNodeName());
        String name = currentNode.getNodeName();
        if(name.contains("Status")) {
            value = currentNode.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(value);
            //result.put("result", value);
        }else if(name.contains("ReturnMessage")) {
            value = currentNode.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(value);
            //result.put("result", value);
        }
        getChildren(currentNode);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get your question, do you want to have `private Node getChildren(Node n)` method? In this case what kind of problem do you face?

Comment: I have this method getChildren(Node n) to get the value of the returnMessage Node, but when this method calls itself over again, the String value becomes empty again. So I'm having trouble returning the nodeValue. How can I save the Node value and return back to the calling method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). In this case you could get the `<axis2:ReturnMessage>` value with the two following lines:

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String returnMessage = xPath.compile("//Detail//ReturnMessage").evaluate(dom));
```

In `//Detail//ReturnMessage` particular case I fetch the first `ReturnMessage` assuming that it has an ancestor element `Detail`. You could modify this fetching logic according to your needs.

**EDIT**: here's the complete source as per OP's request:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("c://tmp//tmp.xml"));

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        System.out.println(xPath.compile("//Detail//ReturnMessage").evaluate(dom));
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Pauk - If the namespace is different every time like sometimes it has a prefix like this  <axis2ns7:ReturnMessage> or          axis2ns8:ReturnMessage> , and can Xpath compile if Detail has a prefix like this - <soapenv:Detail>, So will this work in this case       xPath.compile("//Detail//ReturnMessage").evaluate(dom));

Comment: I've tested this solution with your sample data so the answer is yes, it works with prefixes.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the complete code. Do you feel like it's the answer to your problem?